# ReferenceError: "variable" is not definied

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to pass a variable from a page to another.

I have definied the variable in my Homepage, and I want to use this variable in the App.js page (the page that is load when the app start and where I definied the Routers and the Scenes).

I need to pass this variable to App.js page, because I want check the user's role, and if the role is equal to "plus" don't show a text in the navbar.

But I don't know why I receive this error about variable(isLogged) not definied.

**Homepage.js**

```
export function RolesFunction(){
  var Roles = global.user.data.Roles;
  var isLogged = false;
  if (Roles === "PLUS") {
    isLogged = true;
  }
  return isLogged
}

class Homepage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
```

**App.js**

```
import {RolesFunction} from './Scenes/Homepage';

export default class App extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    isLogged =  RolesFunction()
  }
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
<Scene
  key="homepage"
  component={Homepage}
  type="reset"
  leftTitle="Home"
  leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
  rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  rightTitle={isLogged == true ? "Logout" : ""}
  onRight={
  isLogged == true
     ? () => (App.logout())
     : () => {}
           }
/>
```

So when I start the App I receive the error:

> ReferenceError: isLogged is not defined
>
> This error is located at:
>
> ```
> in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
> in RCTView (at View.js:45)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
> in RCTView (at View.js:45)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
> ```

Comment: Pass data through the state, not through globals.

Comment: Thank for your reply! Can you suggest me how to do?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Comment: please define `isLogged` in `App.js` that is the error

Comment: @NabeelK How can I do? I have tried but I receive this error always

Answer (score 0):

`isLogged` is a **local** variable within `RolesFunction` (which `RolesFunction` returns the value of). If you want to store that return value in *another* variable called `isLogged` in your other component, you need to declare it in an appropriate scope (or, more likely, store it as a property — perhaps a `state` property — in your component).

You're getting the value once in `componentDidMount`. You could store that for use in `render` as a component property, or just get it in `render` unless it's expensive to get (which, from the code you've shown, it isn't).

So just:

```
import {RolesFunction} from './Scenes/Homepage';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const isLogged = RolesFunction();
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene
          key="homepage"
          component={Homepage}
          type="reset"
          leftTitle="Home"
          leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
          onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
          rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
          rightTitle={isLogged == true ? "Logout" : ""}
          onRight={
            isLogged == true
              ? () => (App.logout())
              : () => {}
          }
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Side note: When you already have a boolean value, there's no point to `== true` or `=== true` or similar. Just use the boolean you already have:

```
import {RolesFunction} from './Scenes/Homepage';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const isLogged = RolesFunction();
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene
          key="homepage"
          component={Homepage}
          type="reset"
          leftTitle="Home"
          leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
          onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
          rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
          rightTitle={isLogged ? "Logout" : ""}
          onRight={
            isLogged
              ? () => (App.logout())
              : () => {}
          }
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this solution but now I receive the erorr: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined (In App.js)

Comment: @Jack23 - That would be a completely different problem.

Comment: What about it is??

Comment: @Jack23 - It doesn't have anything to do with your `isLogged` variable, which is what your question is about. Apparently, sometimes `global.user` isn't defined yet when `render` runs. So you'll want to handle that in `render` (or don't try to render this component until it's set). As Rory said, though, globals are generally a poor way to share data between components. If you need something "global" to a component tree, consider using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
contructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.isLogin = fasle
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.isLogin = func() // Do smt
}
```

hope it help you, sr for my english :D

Answer (score 0):

Variable `isLogged` is undefined in scope of render function. Try to write it to the component state in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const isLogged =  RolesFunction()
    this.setState({ isLogged })
}
```

And then access it via state in the `render` function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
        <Scene
    key="homepage"
    component={Homepage}
    type="reset"
    leftTitle="Home"
    leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
    onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
    rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
    rightTitle={this.state.isLogged == true ? "Logout" : ""}
    onRight={
        this.state.isLogged == true
        ? () => (App.logout())
        : () => {}
    }/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried but I receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

Inside your App.js add a constructor and define isLogged using your function doing:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state={isLogged:false}
 }

componentDidMount=()=>{
this.setState({isLogged: RolesFunction()})
}
```

then check the variable using `this.state.isLogged` inside your render function

As of the second error you are getting,  your global variable isn't defined in the moment you start your app, leaving global.user equals to undefined.

The moment you try to read `global.user.data.Roles` it breaks as it cannot find the variable user.

You have to define that variable before you reach that screen, or define it inside that screen

Comment: Thank for your reply, 
I have tried to do in this way, but now I receive the erorr: "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" (in App.js)

Comment: Then global.user.data is not defined yet,  i'll edit my answer

Comment: So I do like this? this.state.isLogged == true ....... 
I have tried to use your update code but the error is the same

Comment: The problem is that this variable is defined when the user click on the login button

Comment: Which login button are you talking about?  Can't find it in your code, it's probably defined deeper down in your code.

Comment: Yes I only explain where is definied the global.user.

Answer (score 0):

please define `isLogged` in `App.js` that is the error. use `this.isLogged` instead of `isLogged`

**App.js**

```
import {RolesFunction} from './Scenes/Homepage';

export default class App extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    this.isLogged =  RolesFunction()
  }
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
<Scene
  key="homepage"
  component={Homepage}
  type="reset"
  leftTitle="Home"
  leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
  rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  rightTitle={isLogged == true ? "Logout" : ""}
  onRight={
  this.isLogged == true
     ? () => (App.logout())
     : () => {}
           }
/>
```

Comment: How can I do? I have tried but I receive this error always

Comment: I have tried to do in this way, but now I receive the erorr: "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" (in App.js)

Comment: I think that is coming from `var Roles = global.user.data.Roles;` this line in `Homepage.js`. What are u doing with that line ?

Comment: I take the Roles directly from the login (I use AsyncStorage to do this)

Comment: global is not having user data. thats y its giving error. please debug and fix it. these are basic programming issues. Please accept the answer or give an upvote